# MySQL: Transaction isolation levels, deadlocks

Tags: mysql, transactions, isolation-level, database-deadlocks

I have a long running process which import products and from time to time I get deadlock errors. According to my knowledge I thought that if during script execution I'll switch isolation level to `Serializable` I will solve an issue with deadlocks. But, what can I do, I can open 2 terminals and reproduce deadlock with `Serializable`.

```
conn1: SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALAZIBLE;
conn1: START TRANSACTION;
conn2: START TRANSACTION;
conn1: UPDATE core_config_data set value = 1 WHERE config_id = 1;
conn2: UPDATE core_config_data set value = 1 WHERE config_id = 2;
conn1: UPDATE core_config_data set value = 1 WHERE config_id = 2; waiting...
conn2: UPDATE core_config_data set value = 1 WHERE config_id = 1; ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

Ok, after it I tried `dirty reads` with `READ UNCOMMITED`:

```
conn1: SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
conn1: START TRANSACTION;
conn1: SELECT junk FROM employees WHERE employee_id = 1; junk=test;
conn2: START TRANSACTION;
conn2: update employees set junk='test1' where employee_id = 1;
conn1: SELECT junk FROM employees WHERE employee_id = 1; junk=test;
```

Do you know where I'm mistaken?

Answer (score 3):

Everything is as expected. You simply can't avoid deadlocks just by isolation levels; the isolation level is for integrity of your data *only*.

You may be able to solve many of your deadlock issues by ensuring the same ordering of updated rows. That way the first connection will be able to process to the end without deadlock and then connection 2 will either fail or suceed, too.